# php realtime query result update

Tags: php, odbc, real-time

Well i think the title says it all. I really need to make the page update when there is a new table row data on `mytable` added or removed. Here's my code

EDIT! : THIS IS THE CORRECT CODE

```
<?php

echo '
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;

}

body {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 277px;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow-X: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
          margin-top: 5px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body OnContextMenu="return false;" OnSelectStart="return false;">';
/////////////////////////////
$odbc_dsn = "mydb";
$odbc_usr = "sa";
$odbc_pwd = "WH@tTH3!?";
/////////////////////////////

$ID = 0;

if(!isset($_GET['myid'])) { exit('Game fail!'); }
$ID = $_GET['myid'];

$conn = odbc_connect($odbc_dsn, $odbc_usr, $odbc_pwd);

if(!$conn) { die('Epic Fail!'); }

$query = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE USER_ID='$ID'");
$world = odbc_result($query, 'MAIN_CH');
$chan  = odbc_result($query, 'SUB_CH');
odbc_free_result($query);

$query = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT USER_INDEX_ID FROM mytable WHERE MAIN_CH=$world AND SUB_CH=$chan     ORDER BY USER_INDEX_ID");
$chanCount = odbc_num_rows($query);

$s = "";
while($i=odbc_fetch_array($query))
$s .= $i["USER_INDEX_ID"].",";
$s = rtrim($s,",");
odbc_free_result($query);

$query = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT USER_NICKNAME, Level, AdminLevel FROM mytable0 WHERE USER_INDEX_ID     IN ($s) ORDER BY AdminLevel DESC, Level DESC, Experience");
while($i=odbc_fetch_array($query)) {

    if($i['AdminLevel']==0){
    echo '<font color="White">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"."Lv.".$i['Level']." ".$i['USER_NICKNAME']."    </br></br></font>";
        } else {}

}
odbc_free_result($query);


odbc_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is not how the http technology works basically. You cannot send data to users on a server side event. There is this new technology that's kicking in which may allow you to do that and it is called WebSockets. There's also polling and long-polling you can use. A simple search for these three methods will provide enough information for you. Good luck :P